# how to run block of code only in release mode in android

Tags: android

I have two builds variant one is in debugging and other is release. I have to run some block of code in release mode. 
For example, I have to use Firebase only in the release build,Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

For Check the release mode use

```
 if( BuildConfig.BUILD_TYPE.equalsIgnoreCase("release")) {

   }
```

debug mode check

```
 if( BuildConfig.BUILD_TYPE.equalsIgnoreCase("debug")) {

   }
```

or you can use this code

```
  if( BuildConfig.DEBUG ){
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

use `BuildConfig.DEBUG` to check is in debug mode